# MVC (in SItefinity)

Tags: model-view-controller, sitefinity

In my View I have something like:

```
@model  CreatorModel

<form name="myForm" action="/Creator/CreateAction" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" method="post">           

           <div class="a">
               <h2 class="a">....</h2>
              <div class="b">
                 <br />
                   Select a file for a <input type="file" name="aFile" id="aFile" />
                 <br /><br />
                   Select a file for b<input type="file" name="bFile" id="bFile" />
                 <br /><br />
                 <input type="submit" id="CreateAction" name="CreateAction" value="CreateAction" />       
          </div>

</form>
```

---

But I have an error : `File /Creator/CreateAction is not found (CreateAction is an action from CreatorController)`

What can I enter as action in `<form...>` in order to find action from controller?

When I'm using this syntax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Board", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { <input type="file" /> <input type="submit" /> }
```

I also have an error: `A reference is not set to an instance of an object"`

Maybe there is a bad routing?

Answer (score 2):

when using MVC widgets in Hybrid mode (on a webforms template) you need to use a special version of BeginForm (because webforms only allows one form on the page).

```
@Html.BeginSitefinityForm()
```

should be the form you use to define a form area in your widget. Replace the regular one with that and the widget should work as expected.

I hope this is helpful!